# How to expand/collapse status bar through ADB?

Tags: android, shell, android-service, adb, android-statusbar

Is there any way to expand/collapse status bar of Android phone over `ADB`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

*Shell* into the device (with `adb shell`) and use the following commands to expand/collapse status bar:

```
# Expand status bar
service call statusbar 1
# Collapse status bar
service call statusbar 2
```

*Note: If device is rooted the commands may need to be called as `su` (with `adb shell su`)*.

---

<sup>The service call was tested on a non-rooted device.</sup>

Comment: Plus 1 for this - Thanks alot. Also 'service call statusbar 7' for expand it full can be used

Answer (score 13):

Another way. By using "`adb shell cmd`"

1. Expand

`adb shell cmd statusbar expand-notifications`

2. Collapse

`adb shell cmd statusbar collapse`

3. You can expand quick settings also

`adb shell cmd statusbar expand-settings`

Please check [help](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/statusbar/StatusBarShellCommand.java?q=onHelp&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject:frameworks%2Fbase%2Fservices%2Fcore%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fandroid%2Fserver%2Fstatusbar%2F) for more:

`adb shell cmd statusbar help`

Comment: Any idea how I can make it work on **Windows Subsystem for Android**?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to pull the notification information of an android device to your shell over adb, you can use this command
`adb shell dumpsys notification`

If you want to **drag down** the notification area, you can try [mokeyrunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html).

Comment: Please add some more information to your answer and describe, why this command is going to solve the problem. Otherwise, your answer might get deleted for poor quality.