# How to expand/collapse navigation bar on iOS 17 device through command line?

Tags: ios, navigation, appium-ios, mobile-development, ios17

I have an iPhone 12 mini with iOS 17.1.2 version number paired to a mac mini M2 pc and i want to handle navigation bar (status bar) through command line. Generally i want a solution similar to this for iOS: [How to expand/collapse status bar through ADB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082954/how-to-expand-collapse-status-bar-through-adb)

I know that some command line tools have been removed from the latest Xcode 15 version for security reasons. For example im trying to find a proper command using *xcrun devicectl* tool but it seems that there is no subcommand related to this. If anyone has an idea or any solution to suggest it would help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can just implement a couple of TouchActions that swipe the correct coordinates